# Calculating angle between two points using ATAN/ATAN2 where x2 - x1 = 0

Tags: google-sheets, trigonometry

Using **Google Sheets**, I've got to calculate the angle between two points with an X and Y coordinate. I've been using ATAN and that works really well when the points are at two unique X and Y coordinates, I get given the angle and then from there I can determine whether it fits prescribed criteria.

The problem I've been running into is when both points fall on the same X coordinate.

`TAN(theta) = Y2 - Y1 / X2 - X1`

Rearranged to

`ATAN(Y2-Y1/X2-X1) = theta`

With the example points (16,16) and (16,6) the X2-X1 comes to zero and then the formula won't run due to the denominator being zero.

ATAN2 solves problems with two Y coordinates being identical but I'm yet to find a solution for having two of the same X coordinate. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ATAN2 works when either `X2=X1` or `Y2=Y1`.  BTW: `Y2-Y1/X2-X1` should be `(Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)`

Comment: ATAN2 isn't working since X2 - X1 solves to 0 and the division isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

[`ATAN2()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093468?hl=en) allows for 2 or 1 argument call.

To get a full [-pi...pi] result and cope with OP's case where `x1 == x2`, use the 2 argument form:

```
ATAN2(X2-X1, Y2-Y1)
```

---

OP posted `TAN(theta) = Y2 - Y1 / X2 - X1`.  Hopefully OP was really doing `TAN(theta) = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the angle between the two points is just twice the (acute) angle from one of the points to the x-axis. It doesn't matter which point on the x-axis, so long as it's on the same side of the y-axis as that point.